# How do I merge two sets of data with Pandas in Pyhton without losing rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using Pandas in Python to compare two data frames. I want to match up the data from one set to another.

**Dataframe 1**

| Name |
| --- |
| Sam |
| Mike |
| John |
| Matthew |
| Mark |

**Dataframe 2**

| Name | Number |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | 76 |
| John | 92 |
| Mark | 32 |

**This is the output I would like to get:**

| Name | Number |
| --- | --- |
| Sam | 0 |
| Mike | 76 |
| John | 92 |
| Matthew | 0 |
| Mark | 32 |

**At the moment I am doing this**

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('data_frame1.csv', usecols=['Name', 'Number'])
df2 = pd.read_csv('data_frame2.csv')
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'Name')
df3.set_index('Name', inplace = True)
df3.to_csv('output.csv')
```

However, this is deleting the names which do not have a number. I want to keep them and assign 0 to them.

Comment: Read this https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.merge(..., , how = 'outer')` this keep all row and insert for them `Nan` and then use `.fillna(0)` and insert `0` for `Nan`:

```
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'Name', how = 'outer').fillna(0)

    Name      Number
0   Sam       0
1   Mike      76
2   John      92
3   Matthew   0
4   Mark      32
```

With `pd.merge(..., , how = 'outer')` you consider two DataFrame if you want megre one DataFrame with another you can merge like below, see this example:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Mike','John','Mark','Matthew']})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Mike','John','Mark', 'Sara'], 'Number' : [76,92,32,50]})

>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Name', how='outer').fillna(0)
    Name    Number
0   Mike     76.0
1   John     92.0
2   Mark     32.0
3   Matthew  0.0
4   Sara     50.0

>>> df1.merge(df2,on='Name', how='left').fillna(0)
    Name     Number
0   Mike     76.0
1   John     92.0
2   Mark     32.0
3   Matthew  0.0
```